# CRON job cURL command doesn't download content

Tags: curl, cron, cpanel

I want to download an XML file to my apache server every five minutes, replacing the old file without prompting.

```
curl-s https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requesttype=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1.25&mostRecentForEachStation=constraint &> /home/myserver/public_html/metarfiles/db/metars.xml &> /home/myserver/public_html/metarfiles/db/metars.xml
```

I am using CRON jobs within CPanel to automate the downloads as this would bypass the CORS issue we encounter within the main .js code. I can then just read the local file

The metar.xml file appears and is updated every minute but its empty. The URL itself renders an xml file that contains data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using wget -O.  Worked right away